# Order date stored as VARCHAR in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

The .NET code, `DateTime.Now.ToString()` outputs something like this:

`11/28/2011 1:17:05 PM`

I store it in MySQL as a `VARCHAR`.

When I `SELECT` it back to my DataTable, I would like it to be ordered. Of course since it's a `VARCHAR`, a simple `ORDER BY` will sort it alphabetically and not chronologically.

Is there a way to `ORDER BY` this chronologically, using SQL?

Comment: Why not store it as a DATETIME? Otherwise every time you want to order by that column MySql will have to convert every value, which will be time consuming if the table becomes large.

Comment: @James I don't disagree, but sometimes you are on legacy systems, and cannot help how data is stored.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will want the [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

```
SELECT columns
FROM table
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(varCharDateColumn, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s')
```

Comment: Quick and easy! Thank You. This works for me: STR_TO_DATE(VarcharDateColumn, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s')

Comment: What about if the time is in 12 hours format i.e. contains AM, PM

Comment: @SajeebAhamed, I don't have mysql to test with, but I think you add ' %tt' to the end of the format, then have that in the string you're formatting as well.  It's the best I can tell from the docs without the engine to play with.